# Alert box error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to allow only alphabets to the text box. I have validated through JavaScript on text box using "on blur". The alert from the JavaScript remains open even though I try to close.

Find the demo link and the JavaScript below.

Note: Type any non-alphabet in the text box 1 and press tab or click on somewhere else from the following link.

http://demo.acclary.com/test.aspx

The JavaScript I used is, below:

```
function checkalphabets(textbox) {
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
if (!pattern.test(textbox.value)) {
    modal({
        type: 'warning',
        title: 'Warning',
        text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
        center: false,
    });
    setTimeout(function () { textbox.focus(); }, 1);
    exit;
    return false;
}
return true;
}


$('.modal-btn').click(function() {

    $('#modal-window').hide();

});
```

Comment: where are you calling checkAlphabets from?

Comment: Using "on blur" event is not a good idea and is creating problem for you.
Instead use OnChange

Comment: You're actually focusing the textbox every millisecond, but when you click the "Ok" button you're blurring it, therefore you're in an endless loop. you should rather listen to the change event or to the input event instead.

Comment: And I saw, you haven't added Jquery library in the page. getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in the console

Comment: Also, you should include your js file AFTER you have included JQuery, as Puneed pointed out.

Comment: Using OnChange is fine. But, not focusing on the text box after clicking "ok".

Comment: @ArunD - If you want the focus back to the text box after Clicking "ok" button of alert, then you have to focus the textbox using foucs function of input ON the Close event of Dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add following line of code in the modal function:

```
callback: function(){ $("#myTextBox").focus();}
```

So After change, it will be like

```
 modal({
    type: 'warning',
    title: 'Warning',
    text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
    center: false,
    callback: function(){ $("#myTextBox").focus();}
     });
```

That's all.
I have created fiddle using the Modal plugin that you are using in the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/7kpsv1p4/1/

Comment: Your answer works fine. But, after closing the alert box, if we press the tab key, it moves to the next text box.

Comment: @ArunD - Change "OnChange" to "OnBlur"... and then try

Answer (score 3):

change `on-blur` to `onchange`

small changes in your code

```
function checkalphabets(textbox) {
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
if (!pattern.test(textbox.value)) {
    textbox.focus();
    modal({
        type: 'warning',
        title: 'Warning',
        text: 'Only Alphabets allowed!',
        center: false,
    });

return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Do you think textbox.focus();  will focus the TextBox AFTER hitting the ok button?

Comment: @Shafeeq, the code is working just fine. But, I want the particular text box to be focused after closing the alert box.

Comment: @ArunD I have edited my answer. Please try it now. called focus() just before the modal

Comment: Puneet, here is the fiddle. But, it is not showing the alert.

https://jsfiddle.net/11so6afp/

Comment: @ArunD - Your problem is solved now, please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29388172/3354492

Comment: I appreciate the effort, Shafeeq. You gave the correct answer too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `onblur` and focus on the textbox together the alert box will always show in the screen, because after focusing the textbox you are closing the modal alert means that you are re-belurring the textbox.

So it's better to use :

- the **[onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)** event.
- Or the **[onKeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup)** event.

**Note:** Using the onkeyup is a better approach to refocus the textbox safely.
And try to focus on the textbox right before showing the alert, so when you close the alert the textbox will be already focused.

**EDIT:**

Here's a **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/dh4z5jzf/)** using the onkeyup event but a simple alert, and here's the code:

```
function checkalphabets(textbox) {
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
  if (!pattern.test(textbox.value)) {
     setTimeout(function () { textbox.focus(); }, 1);
     alert('This is wrong');
     exit;
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It fires whenever you type a wrong character and still focuses in teh textbox.

Comment: Tried both. But, not focusing on the text box after closing the alert box.

Comment: @ArunD take alook at my EDIT.

Comment: Your answer works fine. But, after closing the alert box, if we press the tab key, it moves to the next text box.